# Calling a function to another function vise versa in C

Tags: c, function, call

If I have a function called

```
void do1(int input)

{
do2(1);
}
```

and

```
void do2(int input)
{
do1(2);
}
```

right under eachother, is there a way for do1 function to call do2 function?

Comment: Is your question based on order of function placing?

Comment: Well, *declare* all functions before *defining* them.

Comment: add a declaration for `void do2(int input);` above `void do1(int input)`

Answer (score 2):

Just put a function declaration above

```
void do2(int input);
```

then:

```
void do1(int input)

{
  do2(1);
}

void do2(int input)
{
  do1(2);
}
```

And it will work.